# Pi Calculator Using BBP (Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe) - Written in Cython With MPFR

Tags: python, performance, beginner, reinventing-the-wheel, cython

I wrote a Pi Calculator using the BBP Algorithm in Cython. My specific goals are make the code more legible and more performant. This is a purely academic script in order to teach me how to implement complex algorithms with arbitrary precision (so no monetary gain, it's not homework, but is a personal goal). I have never used Cython before, much less the MPFR library (which is used for arbitrary precision).

My main concerns when it comes to performance is CPU time spent and RAM used. I would like to not have to duplicate the Pi result in RAM just to insert a decimal place. However, I do not know how to make MPFR return Pi with a decimal place. I believe the RAM issue also applies to the use of temporary variables for calculating Pi (in the base-16 or hex) portion of the calculation. As far as I can tell, I am unable to write the code in the format `8*i` in the Cython version due to the need for arbitrary precision. The Cython Code is not a huge fan of "implicit" math against variables of non-default types. I could be wrong and there could be a way to keep the accuracy while using what I call "implicit" math. I have not figured out how as I'm new to Cython (and have not used much C).

An example of what I view as unnecessary variables are the constants named "one", "two", etc... Attempting to perform the math operations with the raw numbers (e.g. 1 and 2) causes compilation to fail as MPFR does not accept integers, but instead accepts mpfr_t numbers. I believe I may have implemented this incorrectly due to what I believe to be unnecessarily complex. I could be wrong and this could be intended behavior.

Edit: I forgot to include the command to compile the Cython file. It is `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace`. You then just run `python3 cpi-cli.py` to execute the script which calls the Cython binary.

The file called `cpi.pyx` is the main file in which the Cython implementation is held.

```
# Slimmed Down Version Of (For Code Review): https://github.com/alexis-evelyn/GeneralProjects/blob/0d59b7bcb78eb9a5ebc46b39d721c71a24a53b23/pi/cpi.pyx

from libc.stdio cimport printf
from gmpy2 cimport *  # mpfr, import_gmpy2

import_gmpy2()  # needed to initialize the C-API

# Modified From: https://github.com/aleaxit/gmpy/blob/879037f2bddccc44bff7ee2fb3ab6a2ff8710bc8/test_cython/test_cython.pyx#L23
# si means long, ui means unsigned long, sj means intmax, uj means unsigned int max, d means double, ld means long double
cdef extern from "mpfr.h":
    # Management Functions
    void mpfr_init2 (mpfr_t x, mpfr_prec_t prec)
    void mpfr_clear (mpfr_t x)

    # Convert Between MPFR and C
    int mpfr_set_ld (mpfr_t rop, long double op, mpfr_rnd_t rnd)
    long double mpfr_get_ld (mpfr_t op, mpfr_rnd_t rnd)

    # Classic Math
    int mpfr_mul (mpfr_t rop, mpfr_t op1, mpfr_t op2, mpfr_rnd_t rnd)
    int mpfr_add (mpfr_t rop, mpfr_t op1, mpfr_t op2, mpfr_rnd_t rnd)
    int mpfr_sub (mpfr_t rop, mpfr_t op1, mpfr_t op2, mpfr_rnd_t rnd)
    int mpfr_div (mpfr_t rop, mpfr_t op1, mpfr_t op2, mpfr_rnd_t rnd)

    # Exponent
    int mpfr_exp (mpfr_t rop, long int op, mpfr_rnd_t rnd)
    int mpfr_pow (mpfr_t rop, mpfr_t op1, mpfr_t op2, mpfr_rnd_t rnd)
    mpfr_exp_t mpfr_get_exp (mpfr_t x)

    # Convert MPFR To String
    char * mpfr_get_str (char *str, mpfr_exp_t *expptr, int base, size_t n, mpfr_t op, mpfr_rnd_t rnd)
    void mpfr_free_str (char *str)  # Free String From Memory
    # size_t mpfr_out_str (FILE *stream, int base, size_t n, mpfr_t op, mpfr_rnd_t rnd)

    # Get Minimum Digits Needed To Hold Number
    size_t mpfr_get_str_ndigits (int b, mpfr_prec_t p)

# Convert To cdef later and figure out how to set return type mpfr (or equivalent)
# Convert "steps: int" to "int steps" and figure out how to set default to 18
def bbp_formula(int steps):
    # import_gmpy2()

    # Define Variables
    cdef long precision = steps*4
    cdef mpfr_t i
    cdef mpfr_t result
    cdef mpfr_t eight_i
    cdef mpfr_t base_sixteen_pi
    cdef mpfr_t convert_base_ten
    cdef char* pi = NULL  # This is a pointer to a string (so no initialization has to be done here)
    cdef mpfr_exp_t exponent = 2  # Should be 2
    cdef mpfr ppi  # Python Object To Hold Pi
    cdef str ppis  # Python Object To Hold String Pi

    # Define TempVars
    cdef mpfr_t denominator
    cdef mpfr_t base_sixteen_pi_part_one
    cdef mpfr_t base_sixteen_pi_part_two
    cdef mpfr_t base_sixteen_pi_part_three
    cdef mpfr_t base_sixteen_pi_part_four

    # Define Constants
    cdef mpfr_t eight
    cdef mpfr_t six
    cdef mpfr_t five
    cdef mpfr_t four
    cdef mpfr_t two
    cdef mpfr_t one

    # Initialize Variables
    mpfr_init2(result, precision)
    mpfr_init2(i, precision)
    mpfr_init2(eight_i, precision)
    mpfr_init2(base_sixteen_pi, precision)
    mpfr_init2(convert_base_ten, precision)

    # Initialize TempVars
    mpfr_init2(denominator, precision)
    mpfr_init2(base_sixteen_pi_part_one, precision)
    mpfr_init2(base_sixteen_pi_part_two, precision)
    mpfr_init2(base_sixteen_pi_part_three, precision)
    mpfr_init2(base_sixteen_pi_part_four, precision)

    # Initialize Constants
    mpfr_init2(eight, precision)
    mpfr_init2(six, precision)
    mpfr_init2(five, precision)
    mpfr_init2(four, precision)
    mpfr_init2(two, precision)
    mpfr_init2(one, precision)

    # Set Variables
    # The BBP Formula Summation (Sigma) Starts With 0
    # MPFR_RNDN means Round Nearest - https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html
    mpfr_set_ld(result, 0, MPFR_RNDN)
    mpfr_set_ld(i, 0, MPFR_RNDN)

    # Set Constants
    mpfr_set_ld(eight, 8, MPFR_RNDN)
    mpfr_set_ld(six, 6, MPFR_RNDN)
    mpfr_set_ld(five, 5, MPFR_RNDN)
    mpfr_set_ld(four, 4, MPFR_RNDN)
    mpfr_set_ld(two, 2, MPFR_RNDN)
    mpfr_set_ld(one, 1, MPFR_RNDN)

    for _ in range(0, steps):
        # Calculate Pi To Base 16 (Hex)

        # 8*i
        mpfr_mul(eight_i, eight, i, MPFR_RNDN)
        # printf("i: %Lf; 8*i: %Lf\n", mpfr_get_ld(i, MPFR_RNDN), mpfr_get_ld(eight_i, MPFR_RNDN))

        # 4/(eight_i+1)
        mpfr_add(denominator, eight_i, one, MPFR_RNDN)
        mpfr_div(base_sixteen_pi_part_one, four, denominator, MPFR_RNDN)
        # printf("Part 1 (4/8i+1): %Lf; Denominator: %Lf\n", mpfr_get_ld(base_sixteen_pi_part_one, MPFR_RNDN), mpfr_get_ld(denominator, MPFR_RNDN))

        # 2/(eight_i+4)
        mpfr_add(denominator, eight_i, four, MPFR_RNDN)
        mpfr_div(base_sixteen_pi_part_two, two, denominator, MPFR_RNDN)
        # printf("Part 2 (2/8i+4): %Lf; Denominator: %Lf\n", mpfr_get_ld(base_sixteen_pi_part_two, MPFR_RNDN), mpfr_get_ld(denominator, MPFR_RNDN))

        # 1/(eight_i+5)
        mpfr_add(denominator, eight_i, five, MPFR_RNDN)
        mpfr_div(base_sixteen_pi_part_three, one, denominator, MPFR_RNDN)
        # printf("Part 3 (1/8i+5): %Lf; Denominator: %Lf\n", mpfr_get_ld(base_sixteen_pi_part_three, MPFR_RNDN), mpfr_get_ld(denominator, MPFR_RNDN))

        # 1/(eight_i+6)
        mpfr_add(denominator, eight_i, six, MPFR_RNDN)
        mpfr_div(base_sixteen_pi_part_four, one, denominator, MPFR_RNDN)
        # printf("Part 4 (4/8i+6): %Lf; Denominator: %Lf\n", mpfr_get_ld(base_sixteen_pi_part_four, MPFR_RNDN), mpfr_get_ld(denominator, MPFR_RNDN))

        # 4/(eight_i+1) - 2/(eight_i+4) - 1/(eight_i+5) - 1/(eight_i+6)
        mpfr_sub(base_sixteen_pi, base_sixteen_pi_part_one, base_sixteen_pi_part_two, MPFR_RNDN)
        mpfr_sub(base_sixteen_pi, base_sixteen_pi, base_sixteen_pi_part_three, MPFR_RNDN)
        mpfr_sub(base_sixteen_pi, base_sixteen_pi, base_sixteen_pi_part_four, MPFR_RNDN)


        # Convert Pi To Base 10

        # 16**i (or 16^i)
        mpfr_set_ld(denominator, 16, MPFR_RNDN)
        mpfr_pow(denominator, denominator, i, MPFR_RNDN)

        # 1/(16^i)
        mpfr_div(convert_base_ten, one, denominator, MPFR_RNDN)

        # (1/mpfr(16**i)) * base_sixteen_pi
        mpfr_mul(convert_base_ten, convert_base_ten, base_sixteen_pi, MPFR_RNDN)


        # Add Result To Previous Results (Summation)

        # result = result + convert_base_ten
        mpfr_add(result, result, convert_base_ten, MPFR_RNDN)

        # Increment Step Counter
        mpfr_add(i, i, one, MPFR_RNDN)

        # Debug
        # printf("%Lf\n", mpfr_get_ld(result, MPFR_RNDN))

    # Convert To String To Import Into Python Object
    exponent = mpfr_get_exp(result)
    pi = mpfr_get_str(pi, &exponent, 10, mpfr_get_str_ndigits(10, precision), result, MPFR_RNDN)
    ppis = str(pi, 'ASCII')  # Convert Pi C String to Python String
    corrected_pi: str = ppis[:1] + "." + ppis[1:]

    # Import String To Python
    ppi = mpfr(corrected_pi)
    mpfr_free_str(pi)  # Free C String

    # Debug
    # printf("Minimum Digits (Cython): %lu\n", mpfr_get_str_ndigits(10, precision))
    # printf("Exponent (Cython): %lu\n", mpfr_get_exp(result))
    # printf("Pi (Cython): %s", pi)
    # print(f"Pi (Python): {corrected_pi}")
    # print(f"Type PI: {type(pi)}")
    # print(f"Type PPIs: {type(ppis)}")

    return ppi  # Pi in MPFR Python Object Format
```

This is the setup.py to compile the Cython script. You need to MPFR library in order to compile it.

```
# Not Slimmed Down Version (For Code Review) Of: https://github.com/alexis-evelyn/GeneralProjects/blob/0d59b7bcb78eb9a5ebc46b39d721c71a24a53b23/setup.py

#!/usr/bin/env python

# The order of these two imports matters greatly
from setuptools import Extension, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

import os

ext_modules = [
    Extension("*", ['cpi.pyx'], libraries=["mpfr"])
]

ext_options = {"compiler_directives": {"profile": True}, "annotate": True}
setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules, **ext_options)
)
```

This is the script to run the Cython binary. I call it cpi_cli.py.

```
# Slimmed Down Version Of (For Code Review): https://github.com/alexis-evelyn/GeneralProjects/blob/0d59b7bcb78eb9a5ebc46b39d721c71a24a53b23/cpi_cli.py

from cpi import bbp_formula

from gmpy2 import mpfr

import gmpy2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    steps: int = 100

    gmpy2.get_context().precision = steps*4

    # Usually at least 2 digits are incorrect (at the end).
    # The full script has a variable called "lost_digits" to adjust how many digits to toss.
    print(str(bbp_formula(steps))[:-2])
```

This is the pure Python implementation of BBP that I wrote and then translated to Cython. This part is not for code review (although I won't complain if any suggestions are made). I included this for a short and legible version of the Cython implementation. I call it bbp.py.

```
# Slimmed Down Version Of (For Code Review): https://github.com/alexis-evelyn/GeneralProjects/blob/0d59b7bcb78eb9a5ebc46b39d721c71a24a53b23/pi/bbp.py

from gmpy2 import mpfr

import gmpy2

def bbp_formula(steps: int = 18) -> mpfr:
    # The BBP Formula Summation (Sigma) Starts With 0
    result: mpfr = mpfr(0)

    for i in range(0, steps):
        eight_i: mpfr = mpfr(8*i)
        base_sixteen_pi: mpfr = 4/(eight_i+1) - 2/(eight_i+4) - 1/(eight_i+5) - 1/(eight_i+6)
        convert_base_ten: mpfr = (1/mpfr(16**i)) * base_sixteen_pi

        result: mpfr = result + convert_base_ten

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    steps: int = 100
    precision: int = steps*4

    gmpy2.get_context().precision = precision

    # Usually at least 2 digits are incorrect (at the end).
    # The full script has a variable called "lost_digits" to adjust how many digits to toss.
    print(str(bbp_formula(steps=steps))[:-2])
```

Comment: I fixed my breaking gmpy2 by compiling gmp, mpfr, mpc, and gmpy2 from source. I should note that I had to ensure I used python3 and not python when performing the gmpy2 install. I may not have needed to compile gmp, mpfr, and mpc as it was available in homebrew, but I didn't notice that I was using the wrong version of Python (Python 2) until after I compiled and installed the libraries from source. It works now so I can continue development.